# The IBM WebSphere JAX-WS Web service runtime in WebSphere Application Server V8.5 Liberty Profile does not support the service project

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, websphere, jax-ws

I'm trying to upgrade a legacy webservice from Axis1 to JaxWS. I've been trying out various tutorials to see if I can add a JaxWS Webservice to the existing WebSphere server we use. I'd like to use the WebService Wizard since that seems like the most likely way to get everything running smoothly, however I've encountered the following problem. When I change the Web Service Runtime from AXIS to WebSphere JAX-WS I get the message

> The IBM WebSphere JAX-WS Web service runtime in WebSphere Application
>   Server V8.5 Liberty Profile does not support the service project <
>   jax-ws project name >

So far google has failed to find a solution or even an explanation of this error for me. Does anyone here understand what my error is?

Thanks,

Comment: Ensure you are using Liberty with Extended content. The easiest is to open Liberty server configuration (server.xml) and try to add new feature `jaxws-2.2`. Also try to create new Dynamic Web project v3.0, add wsdl there, and try to rerun the wizard.

Comment: I can see jaxws-2.2 in the feature manager. This should've been there the whole time. I've tried now creating a fresh workspace in case there was some older, unknown setting that was breaking it. Now when I try to use the webservices wizard I get a pop up when I click next warning me that "The project is targeted against a server without IBM WebSphere JAX-WS support.  Continuing code generation will result in compilation errors."

Comment: I'm running Eclipse Luna, WDT, and Liberty 8.5.5.3. I can generate jax-ws service from wsdl and test it. I had your error, when extended content was not installed and later recognized by Eclipse. Go to `Window > Preferences > Server > Runtimes` , select correct Liberty runtime, do `Edit > Advanced options` and click `Refresh` to update runtime capabilities in Eclipse. And make sure, you are selecting correct runtime, if you have more than one. See if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried this, [refresh] definitely did a bunch of work but I still get the same error. I've confirmed that my eclipse has the JASWS tools addon. My liberty profile also is definitely the extended edition with jaxws-2.2 enabled. Something is still smells funky though. If I ignore the warning about targeting a server that doesn't support jaxws I eventually get an error that "Tools for the targeted server must be installed in order to generate Web services code.".

Comment: I am exactly facing the same issue as @kutuzof

Comment: Hi @Dhrubo I managed to get it working eventually. Essentially what I ended up doing was using the spring web service wizard. I also used an excel sheet where I documented my attempts at every possible combination of wizard parameters. This was the tutorial I used to create the WS: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example-document-style/. I also need to use a SOAP interceptor to manipulate the incoming AND outgoing messages to make them compatible with the old clients and the new server: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-soap-handler-in-server-side/